# How Camel split/iterate over the list and send to queue individually?

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am new to camel, unable to figure out sending individual entity out of list to queue.

```
private void addIncomingFixMessageRoute() {     
    from(Endpoints.FIX_MESSAGE_IN_ROUTE)
    .routeId("IncomingFixMessageRoute")
    .bean(fixMessageTransformer, "transform")
    .marshal().json()
    .to("activemq:queue:feed");
}
```

Here the **transform** method of the bean ***fixMessageTransformer*** returns `List<String>`, now I want to apply **splitter** which iterates and send each element to queue individually. Unable to figure out how I would achieve it.

Tried by applying `.split().tokenize()`, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the splitter on the body, and it will split it.

```
 .split(body())
   ...
```

Comment: It worked after I placed it before .marshal().json() call.